# Is there a difference infinite sequences and functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

Is there a difference infinite sequences (all elements are natural numbers) and functions ?

I mean for example,

> Is the infinite sequence $$a_n=\left\{0,1,0,1,0,1 \cdots \right\}$$ equal to $$f(n) = \frac 12 ((-1)^n + 1) ? $$

Comment: Yes, the infinite sequence is a mapping (function) from the index set (usually the natural numbers) to some target set (often real numbers in basic calculus and analysis classes).  However functions will typically be defined in more general ways, e.g. $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ means a function defined on real numbers.

Comment: As all others said, there is no difference. Notice that a function needn't have an analytical expression.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thank you for the comment. Can you add a little detail the mean of your last sentence "a function needn't have an analytical expression".

Comment: A sequence can be that of a function $f:\mathbb N \to X$ .... but what if the domain is not $\mathbb N$ or not a countable set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, yes and no but mostly yes.

If you have sequence $\{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, .....\}$ where the $a_i$ are all elements of some set $X$ ($X$ can be *any* set; if it's easier you can assume $X =\mathbb R$)  and you have a function $f:\mathbb N \to X$ sot that $f(n) = a_n$ that is perfectly well defined.  (ALso you can define your sequence as $\{a_k\} = \{f(k)\}$).  So there doesn't seem to be any difference.

And indeed: One can think of it as sequence is function mapping each index to a term.  That seems to encapsulate the essence of both functions and sequences, doesn't it?

.......

If you want to get technical what *is* a function and what is a sequence?  Well... technically a function $f:X \to Y$  is a set of ordered pairs $f = \{(x_\alpha, y_\alpha)\}$ where each $x_\alpha \in X$ and each $y_\alpha \in Y$ and for every $x \in X$ there is *exactly* one ordered pair in $f$ where the first term is equal to $x$.

And what is a sequence.  If is an ordered set of elements in a set $Y$ where every term has distinct natural number index and there is a term for each natural number.  In other words is set of $\{(i, y_i)\}$ ordered pairs were each $i \in \mathbb N$ and $y_i \in Y$ and there for every natural number there is exactly *one* $y_i$.

In other words.... its a function from $\mathbb N \to X$.

.....

But a sequence is a function with domain $\mathbb N$.  If you had a function with an uncountable domain such as $\mathbb R$ then you can not list it as a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There is not. Most people define sequences as functions from the natural numbers, $0,1,2,3,\ldots$

You can see this on the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence#Formal_definition_and_basic_properties) and in almost any "higher level" mathematics textbook which defines sequences.

In your notation, instead of $a_{n}$ some authors may even write $a(n)$ to make this clear.

Answer (score 1):

Commonly an infinite sequence is a function whose domain is the set of natural numbers  and its range is the set of real or complex numbers. 
In general any function with a countable domain is a sequence.

Thus your sequence is  the same as $$f:\Bbb {N} \to \Bbb{R} $$

Defined by $$f(n)=\frac {(-1)^n+1}{2}$$

Comment: Technically a sequence can have any range.  You can have a sequence of complex numbers, of functions of ....  But the domain must be the natural numbers.  One can think of it as sequence is function mapping each index to a term.